# Checking if values from table match the values in ArrayList and showing them in next form

Tags: vba, ms-access, arraylist, contains

Im trying to check if records in one column of the table matches atleast one value of the ArrayList and if yes show those records who match in the next form

I have ArrayList full of strings and i dont know how to check and insert records from table to textboxes in next form, where atleast one of the records data of one column matches one value in ArrayList.

This doesn't work:

```
Public Sub Command42_Click()
   
   Dim NotTrained As ArrayList
   Set NotTrained = New ArrayList
   NotTrained.Add "value1"
   NotTrained.Add "value2"

   DoCmd.OpenForm "form_name", WhereCondition:=NotTrained.Contains(handover_No) = True

End Sub
```

I dont know if i am even able to do this in WhereCondition, or i need to open the next form and insert the data in the textboxes in the NextForm.Load() Sub.

In the next form the textboxes have source control set to the columns in the table from which i want the records to be taken.

Comment: Your question is unclear. What does "show those records who match in the next form" mean? If "insert records from table to textboxes in next form", **based on what** to do that? What correlation exists between the text box the be filled with a specific string? Please, edit your question and clarify this issue, otherwise, nobody can help you in the way you ask the question, I'm afraid...

Comment: `handover_No` is the name of the column in the table. For example if one of the records has value `value1`  in column handover_No, in the next form which opens on click it will show other information about the record that matched like name surname and the handover_No in textboxes that has source control set to those columns in  that table. Sorry for being unclear

Comment: Using strings as a means of filtering/selecting records is not efficient within a database. Far better to use the autonumber primary key of a record. I am not sure why you are building up an ArrayList - look at using the `WHERE` condition of the `.OpenForm` action on a CSV list of ID numbers - `DoCmd.OpenForm "frmShip",,,"ShipID IN(10,11,12)"`

Comment: Ok, i got your advice, i changed it a little bit and now it works on a basis of IDs instead of strings. Is there some way i can have the code like this `DoCmd.OpenForm "frmShip",,,"ShipID IN(ArrayList)"` instead of this `DoCmd.OpenForm "frmShip",,,"ShipID IN(10,11,12)"`

Comment: No, you have to create the list of IDs from your ArrayList. But why are you creating the ArrayList in the first place - it would probably be easier to create the list of IDs rather than the ArrayList.

Comment: Thank you for your help i changed the whole functionality of this process so the problem doesnt even occur, but your advices helped me to get there, so thank you all

Answer (score 0):

Part of the solution is :

You can loop through the range cells and look for existing ones in the Arraylist like this

```
Public Sub Command42_Click()
   Dim NotTrained As ArrayList
   Set NotTrained = New ArrayList
    Dim I As Long, LR As Long
    Dim rng As Range
   NotTrained.Add "value1"
   NotTrained.Add "value2"

  LR = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
   Set rng = Range("A1")
   For I = 0 To LR
   If NotTrained.IndexOf(rng.Offset(I, 0).Value, 0) = -1 Then
        ' the value is not in ArrayList
       ' Do Something
    Else
       ' the value is in ArrayList
'      Do Something Else
   End If
   Next I
   'DoCmd.OpenForm "form_name", WhereCondition:=NotTrained.Contains(handover_No) = True

End Sub
```

I do not know what the structure of your form is, so I can not advise you how to fill it out.

Comment: Im kinda beginner in this, so what do you mean by structure of my form

Comment: @xShen You provided answer for `Excel` but OP looking for `MS-Access` solution.